# Dynamically change NavigationBar Back Button Text from presented ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, back-button, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to change the back button text on a UINavigationBar upon receiving something from the network - basically replicating iMessage/FB Messenger by adding a new message count to the back button text ie. < Back (1) or < Messages (2)

I can change the back button text from the presented ViewController (in viewDidLoad)

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
barButton.title = @"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

But when I try to use that same code in another method that is called upon receiving a new message, the back button text doesn't change.

Any idea how I can change the back button text from the ViewController **after it is presented**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `UINavigationItem.backBarButtonItem` for view controller `A` is not the left bar button when `A` is on top of the navigation stack, it is the left bar button when `A` is **second-top** of the navigation stack.

That is to say, you push `A`, and then push `B`, when `B` is on top, the left bar button will be `A.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`

So a easy but not so elegant solution would be:

Give `B` a weak reference to `A`, and `A` provide a interface to change it's back button like this:

```
@implementation A
-(void)changeBackTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
}
-(void)restoreBackButton
{
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
}
@end
```

Then `B` call this method to change the back button title when `B` is on top of the stack

Remember to restore the back Button when `B` is popped, otherwise next time push `B` from `A` will show a maybe wrong back button.